# Bash Bug Fix: Reading a text file line by line and acting upon the lines

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

Here's what my script looks like

```
#/bin/bash
touch input.txt
touch output.txt
seq -w 0 999 >>input.txt
input=$(cat input.txt)

for i in $input
  do
    if [ $(($i%2)) -eq 0 ]; then
      echo $i "even" >> output.txt
    else
      echo $i "odd" >> output.txt
   fi
 done
```

Here's the result of running the script and viewing the output.txt file created

```
000 even
001 odd
002 even
003 odd
004 even
005 odd
006 even
007 odd
```

I would like the script to do this for all 1,000 lines of the script, but I get an error message on line 9 saying

```
./tester.sh: line 9: 008: value too great for base (error token is "008")
```

My end goal is for the script to add each number on a line, and then tell if the number is even or odd, outputting to output.txt for all 1000 lines of the file.

End goal output file:

```
000 even
001 odd
002 even
003 odd
...
505 even
506 odd
507 even
508 odd
...
998 even
999 odd
```

From 000 all the way to 999

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate through a file line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use seq as seq and use printf to print your number in the format you like.
Bash arithmetic expansion interprets strings with leading zeros as octal numbers. You can force the number to be in 10th by prefixing it with `10#` like `(( 10#$i % 2))`.

```
for i in $input
  do
    if [ $(( 10#$i % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
      echo $i "even" >> output.txt
    else
      echo $i "odd" >> output.txt
   fi
 done
```

1. Keep in mind that arithmetic expansion `(( .. ))` can do comparisions. It's clear to `if (( 10#$i % 2 == 0 )); then`.
2. I find `printf "%03d" "$i"` to be just clearer in this case.
3. No need to touch a file before `>>`, should create the file aumatically (this can be turned off with some bash set -o option, but I haven't seen anyone use it).
4. `input=$(cat ...); for i in $input` is just bad. [Don't read lines with for](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)
5. I don't like temp files.
6. [How to read file line by line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Your script is just:

```
seq 0 999 | xargs -i sh -c 'printf "%03d " "$1"; (( $1 % 2 == 0 )) && echo even || echo odd;'  >>output.txt
```

If you prefer while read:

```
seq 0 999 | while IFS= read -r num; do 
    printf "%03d " "$num"; 
    if (( num % 2 == 0 )); then 
        echo even
    else
        echo odd
    fi
done >>output.txt
```

Or if you have to have your input.txt file containing `000\n001\n002\n and so on` it's time for a `tee`:

```
seq -w 0 999 | tee -a input.txt | while IFS= read -r num; do 
    echo -n "$num "
    if (( 10#$num % 2 == 0 )); then 
        echo even
    else
        echo odd
    fi
done >>output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. This has gotten me the closest. However, in the end I need two files, an input file containing 000-999 and an output file with the '000-999 even/odd'. The output file has to be read from the input file, and this is where i'm struggling

Comment: The 4th snipped I added after edit (before your comment) does that.

Comment: My only problem is I need the numbers in the like to be added before determined if even or odd. Look at line 507 number 506 in output.txt for example. This should be odd, as 5+0+6=11. How could I produce this?

Comment: So just sum the digits (we call them digits, not numbers....) and then check if they are odd or even. Something along the `(( ${num:0:1} + ${num:1:1} + ${num:2:1} % 2 == 0))` check. 506 is an even number, the sum of the digits in 506 number is indeed an odd number.

Comment: This is very close, though it appears every digit after 009 is being picked up as odd. Any reason as to why this may happen?

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help. The problem was I was not considering my order of operations when using (( ${num:0:1} + ${num:1:1} + ${num:2:1} % 2 == 0)). Marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is a skeleton code for reading a text file line by line and acting upon the lines... Fill the missing part according to your own needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
{
  while read -r line; do
    if (( line % 2 == 0 )); then
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    fi
  done < input.txt
} > output.txt
```

You may also apply pre-processing to the input file with `<(cmd ...)` notation:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
  while read -r line; do
    ...
  done < <(arbitrary-cmd input.txt | another-cmd ... )
} > output.txt
```

This form looks nicer but it spawns a "subshell" and makes it impossible for the code inside the `while` block to modify variables defined outside it, should you have any.

```
#!/bin/bash
{
  arbitrary-cmd input.txt | another-cmd ... | while read -r line; do
    ...
  done
} > output.txt
```

Comment: The command group isn't necessary, if the only command in it is the `while` loop (or if it contains just the one pipeline, as in the last example). Just use `while ... done < input.txt > output.txt`.

Comment: @chepner Right it isn't necessary. But I prefer to have it by default as it's handy for printing a header/footer etc

Answer (score 0):

Your script could be something like

```
#!/bin/ksh
input=$(seq -w 0 999)
for i in $input
  do
    if [ $(($i%2)) -eq 0 ];then
      echo $i "even" >> output.txt
    else
      echo $i "odd" >> output.txt
    fi
  done
```

then your output will be something like

```
000 even
001 odd
002 even
003 odd
004 even
005 odd
006 even
007 odd
```

Then you could grep "even" or "odd" and execute what you need or you could execute your command directly inside the if/else statement.

Comment: Do you know how I can do this for every single line all the way to 999, instead of stopping at 007? It seems to have a problem after line 9.

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in `seq -w 0 999`; do
    if [ $((10#$x%2)) == 0 ]; then
        echo $x even
    else
        echo $x odd
    fi
done > output.txt
```